# XpertMailer (XPM4) SMTP and charset

Tags: php, character-encoding, smtp

I am trying to send an e-mail using [XpertMailer 4](http://www.xpertmailer.com/) via `SMTP`. It is working well, except I get special characters (accented letters) showing up as `?` in my mail client.

I think it's related to the charset, which I cannot figure out how to define with `XPM4`. My code, below:

```
// path to 'SMTP.php' file from XPM4 package
require_once '../includes/XPM4-v.0.5/SMTP.php';

// CONFIGURATION ------------------
$fromName   = $_nome;                   // from name
$from       = $_email;                  // from mail address
$toName     = $clienteNome;             // to name
$to         = $email;                   // to mail address
$subj       = 'Confirmação de Pedido';  // mail subject
$text = 'Confirmação de Pedido';
$html = '<p>Confirmação de Pedido</p>';
// CONFIGURATION ------------------

// set text/plain version of message
$msg1 = MIME::message($text, 'text/plain', 'ISO-8859-1');
// set text/html version of message
$msg2 = MIME::message($html, 'text/html', 'ISO-8859-1');
// compose message in MIME format
$mess = MIME::compose($msg1, $msg2);
// standard mail message RFC2822
$body = 'From: '.$fromName.' <'.$from.">\r\n".
        'To: '.$toName.' <'.$to.">\r\n".
        'Subject: '.$subj."\r\n".
        $mess['header']."\r\n\r\n".
        $mess['content'];

// get client hostname
$expl = explode('@', $to);

// connect to SMTP server (direct) from MX hosts list
$conn = SMTP::mxconnect($expl[1]) or die(print_r($_RESULT));

// send mail
$sent = SMTP::send($conn, array($to), $body, $from);

// disconnect from SMTP server
SMTP::disconnect($conn);
```

I have tried wrapping the text in `htmlspecialchars` using `ENT_QUOTES` and both `ISO-8859-1` and `UTF-8` charsets, but the result is always the same:

```
Confirma??o de Pedido
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

**Update:** OK, so I figured out how to set the encoding and updated my code above. Still, the same results no matter if I set the encoding to `ISO-8859-1` or `UTF-8`...

Comment: In the headers, or everywhere? In the headers you need to use RFC2047 encoding; if this library doesn't take care of that for you, maybe you should switch to one which does.

Comment: Thanks @tripleee. I figured it out. See below.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.

Seems that the [XPM4 documentation](http://www.xpertmailer.com/documentation/mime/message.html) needs updating (or at least to be made more clear). Here's what it says:

```
MIME :: array message ( string content [, string type [, string name [, string charset [, string encoding [, string disposition [, string id [, integer line_length [, string line_end ]]]]]]]] )
```

Notice there's a parameter `name` and a parameter `charset`. I set both to `ISO-8859-1` and it worked.